# libncurses.so.5: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line while installing omnitty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, ncurses

I am installing [omnitty](http://omnitty.sourceforge.net/)  on AWS ec2 instance having Ubuntu.

```
# uname -a

    Linux ip-172-31-37-63 4.4.0-1038-aws #47-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 28 20:05:35 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Getting error :

```
# make
gcc -g -O2 -I/usr/local/include -Wall -DOMNITTY_VERSION=\"0.3.0\" -o omnitty minibuf.o machine.o main.o machmgr.o help.o menu.o curutil.o  -L/usr/local/lib -lrote
/usr/bin/ld: help.o: undefined reference to symbol 'delwin@@NCURSES_5.0.19991023'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:18: recipe for target 'omnitty' failed
make: *** [omnitty] Error 1
```

Comment: will this be of some use ? ...... # readelf -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5 | grep delwin@@NCURSES_5.0.19991023
   161: 0000000000009e60   182 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 delwin@@NCURSES_5.0.19991023

Comment: As my answer is right then my question should also be right so, please vote it up back from -1 if you feel it's right else let me know why it has been downvoted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found Solution :

Added -lncurses and -ltinfo in Makefile

Makefile looks like this :

```
omnitty: $(objects)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  -o omnitty $(objects) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) -lncurses  -ltinfo
```

Comment: As my answer is right then my question should also be right so, please vote it up back from -1 if you feel it's right else let me know why it has been downvoted